# Can we get rid of the red "new" button beside blog?

Tags: support, superuser-blog

I know it hasn't been up for long, but would there be a way to hide it? I figured once I visited the blog it would disappear, but it didn't.

Could we make it one of the "popup at the top" things? Like when you have a new badge.

Comment: Asked on [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/make-the-new-blog-message-disappear-after-reading-it)

Comment: And still nothing from the big guys :(

Comment: Since Max accepted the answer, it clearly is no longer an active feature request. Let's not add this to the tags again...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click on the `new` icon and it will go away.

Comment: It should really be a hand icon on hover then, not the text selection pointer. Don't know about anyone else but I certainly didn't think to try clicking it.